# Encoding 2 numbers into 1

Tags: arithmetic

Say we have two integers, $a$ and $b$. I need a way to combine these numbers into one unique number $x$, such that they can both be recovered from $x$ and no other numbers can be recovered from $x$
There are plenty of ways to do this, but the problem is that I am using this for programming and I only have the following operators:

$+$ $-$ $\times$ $\div$ $a^x$ $\sqrt{}$

I also have sin and cos but I doubt those will be needed. 
Is it possible to encode and decode $a$ and $b$ using just these operators?

Comment: Well, assuming $a,b$ are integers $2^a\,3^b$ stores them as a single number.  Probably not the most efficient solution.

Comment: @lulu Yeah, as you said, I need to be doing this calculation a lot so finding the prime factors of a number each time would not be good.

Comment: What kind of numbers are these exactly?  An answer for integers would be different from an answer for rational numbers.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I just updated my answer. They are integers.

Comment: How about this. Why not just make a number $a.b$, put $b$ to the right of the decimal place and $a$ to the left.  Or does $x$ also have to be an integer?  If so you should state that.

Comment: @GregoryGrant How can I get the decimal part of x using only those operations?

Comment: I figured you could just get it by inspection.  But I see it's a game where you have to recover it with those operations.  I guess you don't have the floor function?

Answer (score 5):

Try $x=2^a (2b+1)$.

This relies on every integer being written uniquely as a power of $2$ times an odd number.

It is easy to recover $a$ and $b$: just divide $x$ by $2$ until you reach an odd number. Then $a$ is the number of divisions and $b$ is easily extracted from what is left.

However, if you need this for programming, then $a$ will be constrained to be quite small, if you use native numbers. In this context, the problem cannot be solved in full generality because you cannot compress all $2n$-bit strings into $n$-bit strings injectively.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, my main concern with this is that I have no idea what the range of the numbers will be, and if they will be too big, and also I'm going to have to calculate this multiple times in a second, so repeated division might not be very efficient.

Comment: @TreFox, there is also the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function), which will allow a much wider range.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether $x$ needed to be an integer. In order to avoid massive numbers in exponentation, we could take
$$x=a+\frac{1}{b}$$
Since $a,b$ are integers, $a$ will just be the integer part of $x$ and $1/b$ will be the reciprocal part, which you should be able to computationally reciprocate and round to the nearest integer (again, if $b$ is too big this may lead to floating point errors but this should be much better than calculating $2^a$ or similar).

Comment: I realised that @Gregory Grant gave a simpler (and maybe more computationally intuitive) answer, but I'll leave this up since maybe the approach works better for what you want to calculate.